# Does a linear map preserving norm also approximately preserve inner products?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose I have distribution on linear map  $D_{\epsilon,\delta}$  over $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ such that for any $0<\epsilon,\delta<1/2$ we have $\forall x$,
$$\Pr_{A \sim D_{\epsilon,\delta}}(\lvert \lVert Ax\rVert^2- \lVert x\rVert^2\rvert>\epsilon \lVert x\rVert^2)<\delta$$
Now given this can I say that $A$ drawn from $D_{\epsilon,\delta}$ also preserves inner product in the following sense
$$\Pr_{A \sim D_{\epsilon,\delta}}(\left\lvert \langle Ax_1,Ax_2\rangle-\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\right\rvert>\epsilon\lVert x_1\rVert\lVert x_2\rVert)<\delta$$
I tried using polarization identity to get the result, I have following thing so far
\begin{align*} 
\langle Ax_1,Ax_2\rangle&=\frac{1}{4}(\lVert A(x_1+x_2)\rVert^2-A(x_1-x_2)\rVert^2) \\ 
&\le\frac{1}{4}((1+\epsilon)\lVert x_1+x_2\rVert^2-(1-\epsilon)\lVert x_1+x_2\rVert^2)\\
&=\langle x_1,x_2 \rangle+\frac{\epsilon}{2}(\lVert x_1\rVert^2+\lVert x_2\rVert^2)
\end{align*}
Now I am not able to go further as  $\lVert x_1\rVert^2+\lVert x_2\rVert^2\geq 2\lVert x_1\rVert\lVert x_2\rVert$.
Any help, comments, hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question can be rewritten: is every approximate linear isometry also an approximate orthogonal transformation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation)?  An orthogonal transformation in 2-D and 3-D must preserve angles.  So, a good starting direction for your is to try finding a linear approximate isometry on one of those two spaces that is not an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: @ClementC. I thought the question was bit long and therefore decided to be more concise in asking the main problem.

Comment: The first equation really is only for all $x$ of length one? If you set $x_1=x_2=x$ the first and the second seem to be quite different with respect to scaling of $x$.

Comment: @gg yeah yeah you are right, missed that. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proved that
$$|\langle Ax,Ay \rangle - \langle x,y \rangle| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2) = \varepsilon,$$
for all vectors $x$ and $y$ of length $1$. Hence for all vector of any length :
$$|\langle Ax,Ay \rangle - \langle x,y \rangle| \leq \varepsilon.\|x\|.\|y\|.$$

Comment: I see what you are saying. By linearity of inner products we get what we want. But also note that $||x||^2+||y||^2\ge2||x||||y||$. Which means we are getting something stronger just because of linearity,  can u comment something on that?. And typo on statement one, square is inside. Thanks

Comment: I see what you mean, but I have no 'fondamental explanation'. If you have already seen the proof of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality), the trick is the same (prove if for vectors of length 1, then use homogeneity), and I have never seen a direct proof without using this trick.